# jQuery .animate() background image conditional statement

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make a curtain effect where when the function is executed while the curtain is down it will go up and vice versa.  Heres what i have so far.

HTML

```
<div id="curtain"></div>
```

CSS

```
#curtain {
    width: 791px;
    height: 449px;
    background: url(/assets/curtain.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 111px;
    left: 265px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
function curtain() {
    if ($('#curtain').css('backgroundPosition') === '0 0') { 
        $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -250px)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    } else {
        $('#curtain').stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    }
}

$("#wall-right").click(function() {
    $("#frame").attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/27748543');
    curtain();
});
```

Nothing happens and I dont get any errors in console.  Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: How are you calling `curtain()`? Also your second `#curtain` selector is missing quotes.

Comment: edited original question to reflect this

Comment: Some comments:  in chrome, $('#curtain').css('backgroundPosition') is "0% 0%" not "0 0".  Also, the $(this) in your first if() branch won't resolve back to the curtain element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a couple of changes but still I am not sure this is gonna be browser-proof.

Update your HTML structure using a `closed` class at the beginning.

```
<div id="curtain" class="closed"></div>
```

​
And update your JavaScript.

```
var $curtain = $("#curtain");
var curtain = function() {
  var isClosed = $curtain.hasClass('closed');
  if (isClosed) {
    $curtain.removeClass("closed").stop().animate({
      "background-position-y" : "-250px"}
    , 2000);
  } else {
    $curtain.addClass("closed").stop().animate({
      "background-position-y" : "0px"}
    , 2000);
  }
};
```

Your condition was wrong in first place and never triggering. Also I change the animation options to make it less cluttered.

Comment: Best way to be sure is not to test on the css string at all.   Use $curtain.addClass("open") when it opens and remove that when it closes.  Test on $curtain.hasClass("open") to determine which animation to run.

Comment: also theres a bug with background-position-y in firefox 2.0  you have to use the background-position property.  Thanks for this!

Comment: @cl0udc0ntr0l, Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it is such.

Comment: I shall do that.  Solving this problem raises another question.  If i have 2 clickable divs, each of them will open the curtain.  However, if the curtain is open and you click on the other div I want it to close the curtain first and then re open.

Comment: Probably related to the `.stop()`, but actually I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what endend up working for me for anyone with the same question.

```
var $curtain = $("#curtain");   
var $frame = $("#frame");
var $url = '';

function curtainOpen() {
    $frame.attr('src', $url);
    $frame.load(function(){
        $curtain.removeClass("closed").addClass("open").stop().animate({
            "background-position" : "0 -370px"}, 2000);
    });
};

function curtainClose() {
    $curtain.removeClass("open").addClass("close").stop().animate({
        "background-position" : "0 0"}, 2000, function(){
            curtainOpen();
        });

};

function curtain() {
    var isClosed = $curtain.hasClass('closed');
    var isOpen = $curtain.hasClass('open');         
    if (isClosed) { 
        curtainOpen();
    } else if (isOpen) {
        curtainClose();
    }
};

$("#wall-left").click(function() {
        $url = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/27748544";
        curtain();
});

$("#wall-right").click(function() {
        $url = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/27748543";
        curtain();
});
```